# Maven Plugin: Manipulate resources during packaging

Tags: java, maven, jar, war, maven-plugin

in my maven project, I've got a xml file in resources. Depending on some input parameter I want the file to be adapted before packaged into a jar or war. Of course, the original file shall not be touched.

It is not an option to create multiple xml-files and select a suitable one, for example, with spring profiles as there can be numerous combinations of contents in the xml file.

So, I thought of creating a maven plugin, that manipulates the file before packaging. Probably, I need to manipulate the file, when maven has copied the file to the target folder but before maven packages the file into the jar/war.

```
@Mojo(name = "manipulate-xml", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PREPARE_PACKAGE)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
    MavenProject project;

    @Parameter(property = "option")
    String option;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {

        if (option.equals("optionA")) {
           // get file from target and manipulate
        } else if (option.equals("optionB")) {
           // get file from target and manipulate
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I could embedded the maven plugin into my project and build the project with

```
mvn clean package -Doption=optionA
```

However, now I am stuck. I do not know, how to get the file from target and even if this is the right approach.

Besides, is it possible during the packaging to prevent some dependencies from being packaged into the jar/war?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what manipulating means, you can use the possibilities of the maven resources plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html).

If you need to modify some simple values inside the xml, use properties in the xml and let the resources plugin replace them during build. The values for the build can be either in the pom.xml or given to maven via `-Dproperty=value`.

If you want to select a different files, define multiple maven profiles, in each you can configure the resources plugin to copy only the wanted files and then select the correct profile in the build.

If the built-in possibilities are not enough, you might even program your own filter for the resources plugin, that might be easier than writing a custom full fledged maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks für the hint. However, the resources pluging does not solve my problem. I want to add and remove certain xml tags and attributes. As far as I understood, the resources plugin can only replace some placeholders.